# Variable garbage collection in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is there a difference between the following variable declarations?

```
Class A {
  private int a;
  A(){
    a= 2;
  }
}
```

VS

```
Class A {
  private int a  = 2;
  A(){
  } 
}
```

Will garbage collection work any differently?

Comment: In the second example you do not specify a visibility modifier.

Comment: what if it has same access modifier?

Comment: How is this question related to garbage collection at all?

Comment: Seriously, is this question actually about garbage collection? If not it should be clarified for future searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in the behaviour of your two initialisations. In the first example the `a = 2` will happen just before the constructor code is called. If you made `a` final:

```
private final int a; //first example

private final int a = 2; //second example
```

Then you would see a difference between what you could do in the constructor:

```
 A(){ //The blank final field a may not have been initialized for first example
 }

 A(){
   a = 2; //The final field Apple.a cannot be assigned for second example
 }
```

Comment: Since it's `private final` wouldn't the compiler just replace all references to it with a literal `2`?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no difference because the java compiler initialize "private int a  = 2" inside the constructor internally. You can use java decompiler to confirm my above statement. So for both GC will work same.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you are declaring `int a` as a member variable of the class. Whenever the class is instantiated, space will be set aside on the heap for that integer. However, the garbage collector only cares about whether or not there are any references to the containing object that has been instantiated. Regardless of what you do with the member variables, the object will stay in memory if there is a reference to it, after which point it's eligible for garbage collection.

However, perhaps you believe there should be a difference? Why is that?